# On global section of Hom-functor on quasi-coherent sheaves on a quasi-affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring and $U$ be an open subscheme of the affine- scheme $X=\text{Spec}(R)$ such that $\Gamma_U(\mathcal O_U)\cong R$.

If $\mathcal E, \mathcal F$ are quasi-coherent $\mathcal O_U$-sheaves, then is it true that $$\Gamma_U\left(\mathcal Hom_{\mathcal O_U}(\mathcal E, \mathcal F ) \right)\cong \text {Hom}_R (\Gamma_U(\mathcal E),\Gamma_U(\mathcal F))$$ ?

Comment: I don’t have access to the book right now, but iirc from Qing Liu, Chapter 5.1, if $U_i=D(f)$ ($f \in R=\mathcal{O}(U)$) is a principal open subset of $X$ contained in $R$, and $\mathcal{F}$ is quasicoherent over $\mathcal{O}_U$, then $\mathcal{F}(U_i)=\mathcal{F}(U) \otimes R_{f_i}$. It follows that a $R$-morphism between the modules of global sections of quasicoherent $\mathcal{O}_U$-modules define morphisms between the restrictions of said sheaves over affine subsets that are compatible between them. So I’d say yes.